# Is it possible to infer the type signature of useCallback for an event handler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using TypeScript with React and am using an arrow function as a callback for a [Material UI `<Select>` component](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/):

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

interface Props {
  value: string;
  onSelect: (value: string) => void;
}

function MySelector(props: Props) {
  return (
    <Select
      value={props.value}
      onChange={e => props.onSelect(e.value as string)}
    >
      <MenuItem value="a">A</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="b">B</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="c">C</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  )
}
```

To avoid passing down a new function every time `MySelector` renders, I'd like to use the [`useCallback` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). While a direct refactor works at runtime, it fails to type check because of an implicit `any` error on the event parameter, `e`:

```
function MySelector(props: Props) {
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    e => props.onSelect(e.value as string),
 // ~ e implicitly has an any type
    [props.onSelect]
  );
  return (
    <Select
      value={props.value}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      { /* ... menu items ... */ }
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Mousing over the `e` symbol in the original shows its type as

```
React.ChangeEvent<{
    name?: string | undefined;
    value: unknown;
}>
```

It's a mouthful, but to fix the error that's what I have to put in:

```
const handleChange = React.useCallback(
  (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<{
      name?: string | undefined;
      value: unknown;
    }>,
  ) => props.onSelect(e.value as string),
  [props.onSelect],
);
```

Can I have my cake and eat it, too? Can I use the `useCallback` hook and still get the type of the event parameter from context?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to solve this currently but I am desperately hoping for a solution as well! The eslint-plugin-react jsx-no-bind rule pushes many developers to use useCallback instead of directly passing functions as props, and the lack of inference leads us to manually source types which can be prone to error.

Comment: Maybe the best we could hope for at this point is some kind of higher-level hook which takes in the target component/prop as args. e.g. `usePropCallback<typeof Select, 'onChange'>((e) => props.onSelect(e.value))`

Comment: Here's a TypeScript feature request that would cover this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38083

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'd do it with regular react. I described each operation step by step so you can try to reproduce them:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import "./App.css";

// First we get the DOM Attributes for the Element we care about:
// => `React.DOMAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>`
// Then we access the field we need
// => `...["onChange"]`
// Then we remove the "undefined" union
// => `NonNullable<...>`
// which gives you:
type OnChangeCallback = NonNullable<
  React.DOMAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>["onChange"]
>;

const App: React.FC = () => {
  // we use this type in the `useCallback` definition directly:
  const onChange = useCallback<OnChangeCallback>((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }, []);

  return <select className="main" onChange={onChange}></select>;
};

export default App;
```

It should be easy to adapt to your component library.

Turned into a generic so it's easier to import and use:

```
export type On<T, V extends keyof React.DOMAttributes<T>> = NonNullable<
  React.DOMAttributes<T>[V]
>;

// Use it with:
const myCallback: On<HTMLDivElement, "onMouseMove"> = (e) => {};
```

Comment: While this works, I'm not sure I'd describe it as "easy"!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't get this type from context because function passed to `useCallback` 'doesn't know' that it will be used as change event handler.
However, You can extract exact event type from `Select` component (below code coud be compressed to a single line but it would be harder to read):

```
   type SelectProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Select>
   type OnChangeCallback = SelectProps['onChange']
   type OnChangeCallbackParams = Parameters<OnChangeCallback>
   type ChangeEvent = OnChangeCallbackParams[0]
```

and now you can use it to type function passed to `useCallback`:

```
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    (e:ChangeEvent) => props.onSelect(e.value as string),
    [props.onSelect]
  );
```

This way you don't have to 'manually' copy event type.